# Form upload does not work when flask, apache, mod_wsgi, and Windows are combined

Tags: python, windows, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I am developing a web app and one of the basic functionalities is file uploading. However, I am experiencing a 500 server error with the following configuration:

Python 3.10

Flask 2.0.2

Apache 2.4.51

mod_wsgi 4.9.0

Windows Server 2016

I have form validation in flask which flashes whenever there is an empty field. When I added enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form, I started getting 500 server error on submit - the error occurs before the form validation is executed. It is interesting that the same code works perfectly when I run `flask run` and flask's built in development server. My conclusion is that the problem is either somewhere in apache or mod_wsgi. I followed official documentation and configured everything the same way as it is described there but I have no clue what is happening. I would really appreciate your help, thank you :)